# Forcing 60Hz refresh with 4K monitor

Tags: 14.04, xorg, display, monitor, xrandr

I have a P2415Q Dell and it's been working brilliantly. Then this morning it inexplicably started refreshing at 30Hz and I cannot seem to set it back to 60Hz (there is no option higher than 30Hz in nvidia-settings).

xrandr displays it as having a '30+' refresh rate

```
    Screen 0: minimum 8 x 8, current 3840 x 2160, maximum 16384 x 16384
    DVI-I-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
    DP-4.8 connected primary 3840x2160+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 527mm x 296mm
       3840x2160      30.0*+
```

which is further backed up by the sections in xorg.conf:

```
  Section "Monitor"
        # HorizSync source: edid, VertRefresh source: edid
        Identifier     "Monitor0"
        VendorName     "Unknown"
        ModelName      "DELL P2415Q"
        HorizSync       30 - 140.0
        VertRefresh     30 - 76.0
```

[Rest of xorg.conf](https://paste.ubuntu.com/15265383/)

I've tried the (hacky) solution outlined [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/396945/how-do-i-get-a-4k-monitor-on-displayport-1-2-to-show-as-one-screen) but it didn't work. 
Also  I'm sure I didn't have to do anything that involved when I first got this working.

I've also tried forcing it to 60Hz with

```
xrandr --output DP-4.8 --rate 60
```

But that didn't work either.

I've changed drivers, and subsequently changed them back to the recommended one for my GTX960 and the problem persists.

Any tips?

Comment: So this mysteriously started working on its own. I think somehow it was setup to do MST (where you daisy chain two monitors together over the same display port cable) as now it lists the connection as at DP-0 instead of DP-4.8 (The addition of a decimal seems weird).